# Validate data fails with Play2.2.0 and Ebean

Tags: mysql, validation, ebean, playframework-2.2

I am developing an app with Play 2.2.0 and Ebean.
I have a problem when creating directly entities by code, not using a form. Let's say this is my entity :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import models.SuperEntity;

import com.avaje.ebean.validation.Length;

@Entity
@Table(name = "foos")
public class Foo extends SuperEntity {

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 2, max = 2)
    public String code;

}
```

And this is my unit test :

```
@Test
public void testCreate() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.code = "foo1";
            foo.save();
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that the validation annotations seems to be totally ignored. If I set the code to null, I have the database error not a Play error.

```
[error] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'name' cannot be null
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2818)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2157)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2460)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2377)
[error]     at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2361)
[error]     at com.jolbox.bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementHandle.java:205)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.DataBind.executeUpdate(DataBind.java:55)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.InsertHandler.execute(InsertHandler.java:134)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:86)
```

The @Length annotation is ignored as well, I can put the length that I want in the database. The column in the database should be varchar(2) and it is varchar(255).

How can I fix this ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : I have the same errors with annotations like @Min, @Max on Long or Integer properties...

Answer (score 1):

Ebean does not validate data on save.  The validation annotations such as `@NotNull` and `@Column(unique = true)` are used during DDL generation to specify table constraints.  Regarding the `@Length` annotation, it is possible that this is not supported by Ebean, though I can't find the documentation to be sure.  Documentation is definitely a problem with Ebean.  There is a [discussion on the Play git repo](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1518) about the future of Ebean with Play.  It includes information about new/active development on Ebean.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.validation` is not implemented in Ebean. See `com.avaje.ebean.validation` package, but I'd suggest you not to use it.

Comment: Yep it's what I did, Ebean is really unstable and has weird behavior... I ended up removing all Ebean annotations, I replaced them by javax.validation ones and created custom ones when necessary (@Range, @LengthInterval...)

As I can't expect Ebean to validate data before saving (don't know why), I do it by myself by getting a validator from Play Validation factory. Then I get a Set of ConstraintViolation that I can send back to the user with appropriate validation messages.

I still don't understand how Ebean can be embedded in Play, with a website not updated for 1 year...

Comment: As I know Play 2.3 will not contain Ebean anymore. It will be replaced with some new play-thing